# How to import logic using composition API in vue 3?

Tags: javascript, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have a vue 3 script setup component (composition api), and another file (for printing) that has some logic I want to inject into my main component.

My main file looks like

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-table-mobile :headers="headers" :rows="rows" :items-per-page="itemsPerPage" no-data-text="No data to display" pagination-text="{0} - {1} of {2}" :sort-by="sortBy" :group-by="groupBy">
        <template #item.a="{ item }">
          {{ item.a }}
        </template>
      </v-table-mobile>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import * as Print from './utils/print';
export Print;
</script>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
import VTableMobile, { TableHeader, TableColumnSort, TableColumnGroup } from './components/MobileTable.vue';

const sortBy = ref({key:'a', order:'asc'} as TableColumnSort);
//const sortBy = ref({} as TableColumnSort);
const groupBy = ref({key:'a', expanded:[1] as any[]} as TableColumnGroup);
//const groupBy = ref({} as TableColumnGroup);
const itemsPerPage = ref(3);

const headers = ref([
  { key: "a", title: "a" }, 
  { key: "b", title: "b" }
] as TableHeader[]);

const rows = ref([
  { a:1, b:2 },
  { a:3, b:4 },
  { a:1, b:6 },
  { a:7, b:8 },
  { a:9, b:10 },
  { a:11, b:12 },
  { a:13, b:14 },
  { a:15, b:16 },
  { a:17, b:18 },
  { a:19, b:20 }
]);

onMounted(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    rows.value = rows.value.concat([ { a:21, b:22 } ]);
    itemsPerPage.value = 4;
  }, 3000);
})
</script>
```

The print file looks like

```
import { Ref, nextTick } from 'vue';

export default {
    mounted() {
        alert(1);
    },
    beforeUnmount() {
        alert(2);
    },
    methods: {
        async Print(print_mode:Ref<boolean>) {
            print_mode.value = true;
            await nextTick();
            window.print();
        },
        DisablePrintMode(print_mode:Ref<boolean>) {
            print_mode.value = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to add the mounted, beforeMount and the 2 methods to be injected into my main component. But this is not working. How can I fix it?

Right now I get an error

`Declaration or statement expected.ts(1128)` where the `export Print` is.

Thanks

Comment: try `export {Print};` - though, I'm not sure why you would even need to export from main - can't even see where you're using `Print` in main

Comment: I suggest you read thru Vue docs on composables: https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/composables.html It seems you are mixing up Vue 2 `mixin` syntax with Composition API composable, you'll want to take advantage of Vue 3's `onMounted()` and `onBeforeUnmount()`

Answer (score 0):

Vue composables are designed for this.

[Composables | VueJS](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/composables.html)

```html
<!-- print file -->
<script setup>
import { onMounted, onUnmounted, nextTick } from 'vue'
/*
    Other logic code
*/
async function Print(print_mode) {
    print_mode.value = true;
    await nextTick();
    window.print();
},
function DisablePrintMode(print_mode) {
    print_mode.value = false;
}
onMounted(() => {
  // content of this hook
})
onUnmounted(() => {
  // content of this hook
})
</script>

<!-- main file -->
<script setup>
import { usePrint } from './print.js'
const printFunc = usePrint()
</script>
```

> I have written a sample code, you can take this reference to your code